# Initialising defaultValue with select field in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<select defaultValue={(default_value !== undefined) ? default_value : ""} >
```

If `defaultValue` is "", will it select the option which has a value of "" or will it select the first one as the default?

I want to select the first one as default, if `default_value` is undefined.

Comment: Why didn't you try writing code rather than making a question?

Comment: @NguyenThanh Q&A forum. May as well use it as future reference, along with the fact that other people may have this problem and they can just look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give `undefined` in defaultValue, then it will select first option as default, if you give `''` or any value, it will search for that and select that option, but if it don't find that value it will select the first option. Try this:

```
class Logo extends React.Component {
        render(){
            let defaultValue = '';
            return (
                <select defaultValue={defaultValue} >
                   <option value='a'>a</option>
                   <option value='b'>b</option>
                   <option value='c'>c</option>
                   <option value='d'>d</option>
                </select>
            );
       }
}
```

check the `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/cvw7h1th/

Comment: You got it half right. If it's `''` it will go to the `value=''`. `undefined` makes it select the first one. If you change it I can give you the answer